# Failure with start mongod.service on Ubuntu

Tags: mongodb

I try to start service with mongo and get an error:

```
* mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2019-04-12 12:55:29 MSK; 9s ago
     Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
  Process: 15162 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 15162 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Apr 12 12:55:29 mx systemd[1]: Started MongoDB Database Server.
Apr 12 12:55:29 mx systemd[1]: mongod.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Apr 12 12:55:29 mx systemd[1]: mongod.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

If I start mongod by manual, all works good.

mongod.service:

```
[Unit]
Description=High-performance, schema-free document-oriented database
After=network.target

[Service]
User=mongodb
ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --quiet --config /etc/mongod.conf

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

mongod.config:

```
# mongod.conf

# for documentation of all options, see:
#   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/

# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb
  journal:
    enabled: true
#  engine:
#  mmapv1:
#  wiredTiger:

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1


# how the process runs
processManagement:
  timeZoneInfo: /usr/share/zoneinfo
```

I've set permissions for /var/lib/mongodb and /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

- `chown mongodb:mongodb /var/lib/mongodb -R`
- `chown mongodb:mongodb /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log -R`

What's wrong? What should I do? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I've solved my porblem. The solution is very simple, but I had a lot of headace.
Free disk space. I have no anought free disk space in my server. Thats it!

I hope this will be helpfull for anybody...